# duplicating table columns in KDB

Tags: kdb

Consider the code below:

```
q)tab:flip `items`sales`prices!(`nut`bolt`cam`cog;6 8 0 3;10 20 15 20)
q)tab
items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10
bolt  8     20
cam   0     15
cog   3     20
```

I would like to duplicate the prices column. I can write a query like this:

```
q)update prices_copy: prices from tab
```

I also can write a query like this:

```
q)select items, sales, prices, prices_copy: first prices by items from tab
```

Both would work. I would like to know how the "by" version would work and the motivation for writing each version. I cannot help but think the "by" version is more thinking in rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial query would be ideally what you want for your duplicate column requirement.

The `by` creates groups of the column `items` in your example and collapses every other column in the select query according to the indices calculated from grouping `items`. More info on `by` here - http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/select and http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/queries_q_sql#The_by_Phrase

In your example, the column `items` is already unique and so no collapsing into groups is actually performed, however, the `by` will create nested lists from the other columns (i.e. lists of lists). The use of `first` will just un-nest the `items` column, thus collapsing it to a normal (long-typed) vector.

When the grouping is finished the `by` columns are used as the key column[s] of the result and you will see this by the use of a vertical line to the right hand side of the key column[s]. All other columns within the select query are placed to the right hand side of the key.

Comment: so as far as I understand, the collapsing or can I say aggregating function would be, in my e.g. above, the "first" function correct?

Comment: yes - you can consider `first` as the aggregating function in this example (even though it doesn't do anything here). Just to reinforce, there is no need for `first` or `by` if you are simply creating a duplicate column.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of the `by` version coincidentally creates a copy of `prices`.  But `by` changes the order:

```
q)ungroup select sales, prices by items from tab
items sales prices
------------------
bolt  8     20    
cam   0     15    
cog   3     20    
nut   6     10    

q)tab
items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10    
bolt  8     20    
cam   0     15    
cog   3     20
```

The `by` version works only because `items` is unique.  For a `tab` with multiple values for `item` eg. `8#tab`, the query only produces 4 values for `prices_copy`.

```
q)select items, sales, prices, prices_copy: first prices by items from 8#tab
items| items     sales prices prices_copy
-----| ----------------------------------
bolt | bolt bolt 8 8   20 20  20         
cam  | cam  cam  0 0   15 15  15         
cog  | cog  cog  3 3   20 20  20         
nut  | nut  nut  6 6   10 10  10
```

Comment: "by" re-ordering logic, is this random? or based on types?

Comment: Its ordered by the key, in this case `items` are ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental difference between a simple `update` and `update by` queries.

Let's explore it by adding an extra column `brand` to the  table

```
tab2:flip `items`sales`prices`brand!(`nut`bolt`cam`cog`nut`bolt`cam`cog;6 8 0 3 1 2 3 4;10 20 15 20 30 40 50 60;`b1`b1`b1`b1`b2`b2`b2`b2)
```

The following will now simply copy the column :

```
asc update prices_copy: prices from tab2
```

However, the following query is copying the `first item` price regardless of the brand and updating it for all other brands of same item.

```
asc ungroup select sales, prices,brand, prices_copy: first prices by items from tab2
items sales prices brand prices_copy
------------------------------------
bolt  2     40     b2    20
bolt  8     20     b1    20    //b2 price
cam   0     15     b1    15    //b2 price
cam   3     50     b2    15
cog   3     20     b1    20
cog   4     60     b2    20    //b2 price
nut   1     30     b2    10    //b2 price
nut   6     10     b1    10
```

`update by` might be useful in the case where you want to copy the `max` price of the items regardless of the brand or some other aggregation query.

```
asc ungroup select sales, prices,brand, prices_copy: max  prices by items from tab2
items sales prices brand prices_copy
------------------------------------
bolt  2     40     b2    40
bolt  8     20     b1    40    //max price in bolts regardless of the brand
cam   0     15     b1    50
cam   3     50     b2    50
cog   3     20     b1    60
cog   4     60     b2    60
nut   1     30     b2    30
nut   6     10     b1    30
```